# Find common rows between two large matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two large matrices [285600 x 2] and [167830 x 2] matrices.
I would like to find the common rows between them, as well as the correspond indices between them.
Does anyone know a fast way to do this?
Thanks.

EDIT 1: The elements in each column of matrices are not unique, however each row in matrices is unique.

EDIT 2: My code:

```
a <- rbind(m1 , m2)
dup <- a[duplicated(a),]
ind <- mlapply(1:length(dup), function(x) which(m1[,1]==dup[x,1] & m1[,2]==dup[x,2]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little ugly, but it gets the job done. I think the easiest way is to assign the row numbers to another column, and then join the two. I'm more familiar with data tables, so I went that route.

First, some example data:

```
m1 = matrix(c(1, 9, 2, 4, 5, 7), nrow=3,  ncol=2) 
m2 = matrix(c(1, 1, 3, 9, 4, 7), nrow=3,  ncol=2)
```

Then my solution:

```
library(data.table)

m1 <- data.table(m1)
setkey(m1, 'V1', 'V2')
m1[,"index1" := .I]
m2 <- data.table(m2)
setkey(m2, 'V1', 'V2')
m2[,"index2" := .I]

# Join the tables by key #
m3 <- m1[m2]

overlap <- m3[is.na(index1)==FALSE & is.na(index2)==FALSE,]
```

Comment: Do you need to create the index column before keying? Otherwise it won't correspond to the original row order.

Comment: Yes, if you want the original row order you need to create it before keying. In my example I had a preference for it matching after sorting.

Comment: Ok. But it sounded like the OP wanted the original row indices.

Answer (score 0):

Lets call your matrices m1 and m2, with rows r1 and r2 each:

```
row1_matches <- which(m1$r1 == m2$r1)
row2_matches <- which(m1$r2 == m2$r2)
both_rows_matches <- which(row1_matches == row2_matches)
```

That will give you the index values for all matches

Comment: That's the idea. `which` gives the index values for every row where two vectors satisfy some condition, here `==`

Comment: Does it work for common rows in matrices? Assume the first row in m1 is the 10th row in m2, I think something goes wrong with your answer. EDIT: In addition, the elements in each column of matrices are not unique.